# MVC hidden checkbox always submits as checked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

I have something I have to fix asap

In the view I have a hidden checkbox:

```
<div class="D2">@Html.CheckBox("none", false, new { type="hidden", id = "none" })</div>

//Apply button will submit the form
$('#apply').click(function () {
...
     $("#submit").click();
...
});
```

For some reason it always submits as checked when its hidden. If I remove the hidden property it works just fine.
I have to do it this way as its the fastest way to fix the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting a *hidden* property - you're setting the *type* property.

I think you want

```
<input type="checkbox" id="none" style="visibility:hidden;" />
```

not

```
<input type="hidden" id="none" />
```

Try this, instead

```
@Html.CheckBox("none", false, new { style="visibility:hidden", id = "none" })
```

Answer (score 0):

By passing in type="hidden", you are making it so that the element is no longer a checkbox.  It's now a hidden input.  Are you trying to get an *invisible* checkbox?  If so try

```
@Html.CheckBox("none", false, new { id = "none", style="display: none" })
```